# How to split the denominator value from one column and store it in another column using perl?

Tags: perl, cgi

---

My example code output:

```
time         | name        | status    | s_used     | s_max     |
+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 1482222363 | asf         | Closed    | 0/16       |         0 |
| 1482222363 | as0         | Available | 4/16       |         4 |
```

---

1. I have attached the part of my output which is generated using `perl` `cgi` script and `mysql` database.
2. My query is how to take denominator value from the column **s_used** and store only the **denominator** values in the **s_max** column using perl.

3.I had attached the following part of code which i tried.

```
if($i == 4){                    
    if(/s_used/){
        print;
    }
    else{
        chomp();
        my($num,$s_max)=split /\//,$table_data{2}{'ENTRY'};
        print $s_max;
    }
}
```

Code Explanation:

1. `$i == 4` is the column where should I store the variable.
2. I got `time` column from the sql database `$time`, `name` I got from `$table_data{0}{'ENTRY'}`, `status` from `$table_data{1}{'ENTRY'}`, `s_used` from `$table_Data{2}{'ENTRY'}`.

Expected output:

```
time         | name        | status    | s_used     | s_max     |
+------------+-------------+-----------+------------+-----------+
| 1482222363 | asf         | Closed    | 0/16       |         16 |
| 1482222363 | as0         | Available | 4/16       |         16 |
```

Comment: What problem you are facing with this code?

Comment: Am getting the numerator values instead  of denominator values.@AbhiNickz

Comment: What value you are getting in `$table_data{2}{'ENTRY'}`, I am getting the correct denominator value if `$table_data{2}{'ENTRY'} == 4/16`.

Comment: Am getting the above tabular form output whenever i run the above code.In s_max values i should get 16 instead of 4.@AbhiNickz

Comment: @upworkonline What `$num` has? Just print the `$num`.

Comment: $num has numerator values@mkHun

Comment: @upworkonline I don't know what is the actual problem. Bcz it is working correctly. print the whole line and check it `print $table_data{2}{'ENTRY'};`

Comment: can you post the sample code which you have tried@mkHun

Comment: @upworkonline I tried with perl oneliner `perl -e 'my $s = "0/16" ;my($num,$s_max)=split q(/), $s; print $s_max; '`

Comment: Okay i will check it again@mkHun

Answer (score 1):

Seems your code "`my($num,$s_max)=split /\//,$table_data{2}{'ENTRY'};`" is right.

Somehow the value `$s_max` at the time it's writing to the DB is incorrect. Since you did not post the portion of code to show the part `$s_max` writing back to the DB, you need to check what value is in `$s_max` (e.g. printing the `$s_max` value) at the time right before writing it back to DB. From there, please try to trace back why an incorrect value is assigned to `$s_max`. Then, the problem would be solved.